Google OAuth Authentication Fails for Under-18 Accounts
I'm having trouble authenticating some Google emails.
For accounts created for users aged 18 and older, everything works fine.
However, for accounts where the age is under 18, I encounter an error.
Here are my configurations:
HTML:
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
JavaScript:
config_CLIENT_ID = '...';

credential: string = '';

initializeGoogleApi = async () => {
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: this.config_CLIENT_ID,
    callback: this.handleCredentialResponse
  });
}

renderGoogleButton() {
  const parent = document.getElementById('button-google-el');
  google.accounts.id.renderButton(parent, {text: 'signin_with', size: 'large'});
}

Console Error:
//Other domains

m=credential_page_library:66 [GSI_LOGGER]: Parameter approval_state is not set correctly.

//Domain gmail.com

m=credential_page_library:66 [GSI_LOGGER]: An unknown error occurred.

Has anyone else experienced this issue with under-18 Google accounts? Is there a configuration I'm missing to allow OAuth for these accounts?
I'm having trouble authenticating some Google emails.
For accounts created for users aged 18 and older, everything works fine.
However, for accounts where the age is under 18, I encounter an error.
What I've Tried:
I verified that the client ID and OAuth configuration are correct and work without issues for users aged 18 and older.
I tried adjusting the permissions and scopes, thinking that maybe certain scopes are restricted for under-18 accounts, but the error persists.
I searched through the Google documentation to find any specific requirements or limitations for under-18 accounts but couldn't find anything relevant.
What I Expected:
I expected the authentication process to work seamlessly for all users, regardless of their age, using the same configuration. My goal is to allow under-18 users to sign in without encountering any errors.
